# Why the need for IS TRUE operator?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Some SQL dialects such as BigQuery have an [`IS [NOT] TRUE|FALSE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#is_operators) operator. What is the point of this? For example, can't one just do `val=TRUE` or `val!=TRUE`? What advantage does the above operator give us, if it only accepts a boolean input?

I can see its usefulness for something like [Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/istrue) where it allows things like `'1'` or `1` or `'y'` but the above doesn't seem very useful. I suppose one thing it does is give an expected result for `NULL`? For example:

```
select
  true is true,
  false is true,
  null is true

# true | false | false
```

Comment: the point of `is [not] (true|false|unknown)` is to work with three valued logic https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic#truth-value-test

Comment: The `x = true` or `x <> true` would result in NULL/UNKNOWN instead of TRUE/FALSE if `x` is NULL/UNKNOWN, on the other hand `x is true` results in TRUE if `x` is TRUE, and FALSE when `x` is FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what's the difference then between `x IS UNKNOWN` vs `x IS NULL`. Is `UNKNOWN` just an alias for `NULL` ?

Comment: @David542 Basically, yes. You could also ask why you can't just use `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM`; the SQL standard committee decided that they wanted this explicitness in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For once completeness. You have all three predicates:

- `x is true`: to check if the value of predicate x is true.
- `x is false`: to check if the value of predicate x is false.
- `x is unknown`: to check if the value of predicate x is unknown.

Beyond this, in rare cases it may be necessary to distinguish between "predicate x is true" compared to "predicate x is not false". This typically happens for filtering predicates (e.g. the WHERE clause) that use the first form, while constraint validations use the second form.

If you wanted to implement some non-trivial behavior `x is true` can come in handy for constraints.

Comment: I see, thanks for this response, that covers it all. One more thing: why the need for `is unknown` operator if that acts the same as `is null` (`unknown` seems like a sort of alias for `null`) or is that to indicate it's a `BOOL`-only column?

Comment: Unknown is the truth value, that is *represented* by a null. It's just a semantic difference.

Comment: ok, `SELECT NULL IS NULL, NULL IS UNKNOWN` returns `true`, `true` on every database I've tried. Is that expected? In other words, `UNKNOWN` is more just a hint saying something like "We're using this to be explicit that this value should be of BOOL type".

Comment: "SELECT NULL IS NULL, NULL IS UNKNOWN returns true, true on every database I've tried. Is that expected?" -- Yes, those two expression are equivalent. However, the second one only works for booleans, while the first one applies to every type.